# Segmentation Fault: 11 when running C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, int, inline-assembly

To try to display graphics using C, I am trying to take advantage of C's "inline assembly" feature.  I get no errors during compilation, but when I try to run the program, I get this error:

`Segmentation Fault: 11`

Here is my code:

```
int main(){
asm("movb 0xc,%ah");
asm("movb $1,%al");
asm("movw $5,%cx");
asm("movw $5,%dx");
asm("int $0xc");
return 0;
}
```

Constructive criticism appreciated, insults not.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, which line causes the seg-fault?

Comment: 1) You should combine the statements into a single asm("...\n\t....") 2) More importantly: I know of no OS under which this will work (That is even assuming you meant `int $0x10`).

Comment: @OilCharlesworth I have no idea.

Comment: I hope you are on DOS, as everything else would not support software interrupts to access graphics hardware...

Comment: `movb`? `movw`? Is this... DEC Vax assembler?

Comment: @Yann: AFAIK DOS doesn't raise SIGSEGV...

Comment: @Vlad: True, but since we're already trying to do the impossible ;)

Comment: @AndersLindahl  C requires me to use AT&T assembly...so much more cryptic than Intel assembly!

Answer (score 2):

First, it looks like you're trying to use BIOS interrupts to do the graphics, but the graphics interrupt is [int 10h (0x10)](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm), not 0xc, so you want to call int $0x10.

Second, you can't call most BIOS interrupts from within 32-bit or 64-bit Linux or Windows programs, so make sure you're compiling this for DOS. Otherwise, calling the invoke interrupt opcode on a BIOS interrupt will crash your program. And if you run a newer version of Windows, you'll probably still have to run your compiled program inside of an emulator like DOSBox for it to work properly.

Finally, GCC inline assembly has a certain format to it:

```
   __asm__ __volatile__ ( 
         assembler template 
       : output operands                  /* optional */
       : input operands                   /* optional */
       : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
       );
```

So for example:

```
int main()
{
  /* Set video mode: */
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movb $0x0, %%ah \n\
     movb $0x13, %%al \n\
     int $0x10"
    :
    :
    :"ax"
  );

  /* Draw pixel of color 1 at 5,5: */
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movb $0xC,%%ah \n\
     movb $1, %%al \n\
     movw $5, %%cx \n\
     movw $5, %%dx \n\
     int $0x10"
   :
   :
   :"ax","cx","dx"
  );

  /* Reset video mode: */
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movb $0x0, %%ah \n\
     movb $0x03, %%al \n\
     int $0x10"
    :
    :
    :"ax"
  );

  return 0;
}
```

But the optional fields are only really useful if you're writing functions in assembly language and want to pass in arguments from your C code.

Also, I don't have DJGPP and a DOS installation handy, so I can't test any of this code to make sure it works with the 32-bit protected mode binaries it generates, but hopefully I've hit the nail close enough on the head that you can handle the rest yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Hi James, your code of draw the pixel is very useful to me right now, do you know how's the code for getting the pixel color?

Comment: At such a low level, pixel formats and offset calculations will be defined by the video mode used. VGA Mode 13h (from my example) is an indexed color mode, so you'll have to actually copy the pixel data from video memory and compare the values to the color palette entries to get the actual color data. You can read more about VGA graphics programming here: http://www.brackeen.com/vga/